# What is the best approach to avoid expiring root certificates in IoT devices?

Tags: ssl-certificate, iot, esp32

I have esp32-based devices in the field which are connecting to a back-end server that I fully control.

These devices include a [default root certificate bundle](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32s2/api-reference/protocols/esp_crt_bundle.html)

I am worried that one day, all these certificates will expire.

I want to avoid this problem for any future devices that I will deploy into the field.

What is the best long-term solution for the "expiring root certificate" problem?

I have the option for OTA updates, but I would rather find an approach that does not require me to update the devices once they are in the field.

PS: Maybe this is relevant: I will soon be migrating my back end from Heroku to AWS.

Comment: Include the [root CA cert](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/tree/master/libraries/WiFiClientSecure#using-a-root-certificate-authority-cert) of the server, for example, AWS root CA is "Amazon Root CA 1" which is only expired by Jan 2038.

Comment: They will expire some day. Or they may be revoked. If your devices may still be in operation at that time then you have three choices: 1) update the certificates, 2) ignore them and don't validate web servers that your code connects to (this doesn't help for client certificates) or 3) fail. Those are your options.

Comment: @hecheung I want my devices to be able to operate beyond 2038

Comment: @romkey I cannot update the certificates since I don't want to update the devices. That's also why option 2) is not an option. Option 3) is what I want to avoid.

Comment: Well, those are your options. Fail or do something you don’t want to do. I don’t see why updating the certificates is such a big issue. If these devices are meant to work for a long time, you’ll also need to update their software unless you’re the one person on earth who magically writes bug-free software.

Comment: @romkey Can't I create a self-signed root certificate with a really long lifetime, like, 1000 years?

Comment: Field-updating an ESP32 is a pretty standard process and there should be plenty of tutorials available for this. Your software _won't_ be bug free and _will_ have security vulnerabilities. So a device that runs for years without an update will be very welcome to hackers as part of a botnet.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, you could implement what a web browser does. There is a list of trusted authorities that sign certificates.

The easiest and cheapest way is to use LetsEncrypt, even though their service is oriented for https certificates, you could sign your own certificate. After you sign the certificate it is only a matter of going to their site to download the latest root certificate from your embedded device.